# why we write calc in width property? width:100% - 80px; = width:calc(100% - 80px);

Tags: html, css, calc

why we write calc in width property?
width:100% - 80px; = 
width:calc(100% - 80px);
html here
 `<div>any text here</div>`
and css here

```
div{
background:#f00;
width:calc(100% - 10px);
padding:30px;
```

}

Comment: why? because sometimes you want to mix relative with absolute sizes, and the only way to do that is calculating things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code is telling us that your div width is a 10px less than 100% of its container. How else would you do this?

if your parent container is 100% wide (you do not know how wide it actually is(in fluid design)) but you do know that you want it to be 10px smaller than its parent.

To answer your question, why? There are many* different reasons why and everyone will have there opinion on which "why" is more important. Its better that you investigate how it gets used and you decide when you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Because otherwise older browsers could treat "100% - 10px" as "100%" or fail in unusual ways.  With calc() older browsers will fail more properly and ensure compatability.  This is typical is css/html...we're always fighting against the past.